# Images getting from url and how to decrease the image size in iOS

Tags: ios, image

My problem is: I am getting image from server. When I get images from server image size 138x91  but I had given my images size is in my custom cell size 85x56. Its loading good. But when I click row its increase the server image size. How to decrease the image size when i get image in my tableview and how to don't change image size when i click row.how to solve my problem.i want Images getting from url and how to  decrease the image size in iOS.goto bellow link.

1).before click.

[image]

2).ofter click

[image]

This is image getting data code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and loading before i am showing one

```
placeholderimage . newsobject.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];   
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul); 
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumb_file"]]]; 
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];  
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = image; 
  }); });
```

Comment: Give me code you insert image in a row? Maybe when you click a row, this image autoresize

Comment: this is image getting data code in cell for row at index path.and loading before i am showing one placeholderimage .  newsobject.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
                dispatch_async(queue, ^{

Comment: NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"thumb_file"]]];
                    
                    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                   
                [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = image;
                                            
            });
        });

Comment: you should add your code in question so everyone can see that.

Comment: When you get the image resize it.See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715931/get-the-size-of-an-image-after-resizing-in-iphone-sdk/18716348#18716348

Comment: @user3627091 you mean image size is changed when you click row after download?

Answer (score 0):

1. for the image became big problem. check your uiimage's contentMode see if it's what you want, there's an enum for it. you can search
   the `UIViewContentMode` in document for more details.
2. to resize the uiimage you can use some resize functions after you
   get the images from server, then save it or display it. an example
   of resize function:

   ```
    - (UIImage*)resizedImage:(CGSize)bounds upScale:(BOOL)upScale {
       CGSize originalSize = self.size;
       float xScale = bounds.width / originalSize.width;
       float yScale = bounds.height / originalSize.height;
       float scale = MIN(xScale, yScale);
       if (!upScale) {
         scale = MIN(scale, 1);
       }

       CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(originalSize.width * scale, originalSize.height * scale);
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
       [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
       UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

       return resultImage;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
[newsbject.allnewsimg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image_file"]]]

               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"songs85-56.png"]];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@""]]];

                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = image;
        });
    });
```

Comment: when i use this code i can solve my image lazy loading and scrolling problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code.

```
float actualHeight = image.size.height;
float actualWidth = image.size.width;
float imgRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
float maxRatio = 320.0/480.0;

if(imgRatio!=maxRatio){
    if(imgRatio < maxRatio){
        imgRatio = 480.0 / actualHeight;
        actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth;
        actualHeight = 480.0;
    }
    else{
        imgRatio = 320.0 / actualWidth;
        actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight;
        actualWidth = 320.0;
    }
}
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```